# VSTO 2015 ClickOnce Addin AutoUpdate issue

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created a Outlook 2010/2016 addin (VSTO?) with VS2015. I deploy this addin using click-once.
The update settings in the addin are set to every time the customization (addin) runs.

I can install the addin with one click (so far so good) and it remains working if a stop and start Outlook. No issues.....

But when I make a change to my AddIn, publish it and restart Outlook again. The addin is not loaded anymore. It is just not enabled in Outlook. Even enabling it again will not work. I need to uninstall and reinstall the addin to get the newest version available.

I cannot figure out why it is not working as there are no error messages.

Any clue anyone?

Comment: The issue above is for my Dev-machine (Windows 10 Ent v1803, Office 2016 Pro).When I do similar actions on a 32-bit Win 7 Ent with Office 2010 Pro the update process goes without any errors. So far I am unable to find any information about this problem. Anyone here who can shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled) article.